# How to have a timer change amount of a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a timer in the background tracking the amount of time spent on the website, with the timer after 1 minute on the website i want a variable ex. money to add with 1£. With javascript if possible

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i would have done:

`window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){AddMoreMoney();}, 3000);
}`

after the page loads it will call the function `AddMoreMoney()` after every 3000 millisecond / 3 secound.

So if you want to add every minute you need to change 3000 to 60000 ( 60*1000 = 60000 )